# SDL2 Android Asset Path

Tags: java, android, c++, sdl-2

I need to grab the path to the android assets folder for my SDL2 app. I keep getting file not found when I attempt to get the file directly with something simple like:

```
TTF_OpenFont("font.ttf", 24 );
```

What I assume is that I'm looking in the wrong folder (whatever the current working directory is), and that I need to prepend the assets folder path.

Using `SDLActivity.getContext().getAssets().list("");` shows the file i want to load.

Ironically, loading "font.ttf.png" does not result in a FileNotFoundException (I randomly added .png as a sanity check... I'm not sure I'm sane anymore).

I have been loading them fine on other platforms (win, linux, osx).

Comment: If you placed you font file at assets/media/font.ttf in your APK it should work just fine. Did you inspect the resulting APK to verify the file is there?

Comment: Yes I did, I unzipped the built apk... And the file was in there. Does android add magic somewhere?

Comment: Are you using a recent version of SDL? There's two code paths, one for compressed assets, one for non compressed ones, so it's possible this explains the difference you see with one extension (png) versus the other (ttf). If you don't have customizations done to SDL and are using a recent SDL checkout it's worth filing a bug report, ideally with a test case to reproduce.

Comment: I'm using 2.0.3 unmodified, can you point out where I can find more information about this?

Comment: This is where the magic happens: https://hg.libsdl.org/SDL/file/6ec57a81e5d6/src/core/android/SDL_android.c#l681

Comment: Ha! I was just looking at it, I'll print some log statements and see if it is a bug that i can report or something stupid I've done.

Comment: Bwah ha! I found it: I'm stupid. Eclipse was stopping when it had a FileNotFoundException. I turned off the setting to stop on uncaught exceptions, and SDL catches them and handles it fine. Thanks for your help, you saved me from doing lots of work i didn't need to.